# useEffect only on pageload AND page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a functional component that should subscribe to events when the page loads and when the page refreshes and unsubscribe each time the component unmounts. I want to use useEffect for that, unfortunately not successfully. The first attempt removes eventlisteners and adds eventlisteners again each time a new event is passed:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useSnackbar } from '../../context/SnackbarContext';
import { parseRigData } from '../data.utils';
import sse from '../../lib/sse';

export function useRig(config) {
  const { openSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  useEffect(() => {
    const createListeners = () => {
      const newListeners = {};

      config.forEach(instance => {
        const { name, handleData, showMessage, type } = instance;

        newListeners[name] = ({ data }) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log('[RIG] received', JSON.parse(data, 0, 2));
          const messageBody = parseRigData(data);
          handleData(messageBody);

          if (showMessage) {
            const message = showMessage(messageBody);
            if (message) openSnackbar(message, type);
          }
        };
      });

      return newListeners;
    };

    const initializeListeners = listeners => {
      config.forEach(instance => {
        const { events, name } = instance;
        sse.listenForUserMessage(events, listeners[name]);
      });
    };

    const removeListeners = listeners => {
      config.forEach(instance => {
        const { events, name } = instance;
        sse.removeListener(events, listeners[name]);
      });
    };

    const createConnection = async (events, listeners) => {
      if (!events.length) return;
      await sse.connect(events);
      initializeListeners(listeners);
    };

    function getEvents() {
      const result = [];
      config.forEach(instance => {
        const { events, config } = instance;
        result.push({
          eventTypes: events,
          config
        });
      });
      return result;
    }

    const events = getEvents();
    const listeners = createListeners();
    createConnection(events, listeners);

    return () => {
      removeListeners(listeners);
      if (events.length) sse.disconnect(events);
    };
  }, [config, openSnackbar]);
}
```

I understand the behaviour - it happens each time the component updates. Thats why I tried to solve this problem by removing config and openSnackbar from the useEffect-array that defines what changes are being watched for the useEffect to take place:

```
export function useRig(config) {
  const { openSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...same code

    return () => {
      removeListeners(listeners);
      if (events.length) sse.disconnect(events);
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working when I reload the page with f5. In that case, the events are not passed ("can´t perform a React state update on an unmounted component) and the listeners from the return cleanup are not removed. Otherwise, on a normal page load or leaving page it works great.

Is there any way how can I include page reload(but not componentUpdate) to perform useEffect?

Comment: Page load, reload, and refresh are essentially synonymous. `useEffect` with dependency is both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. Are you wanting only the `componentDidMount` behavior?

Comment: I guess what is needed for this case is something like componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount behaviour

Comment: That's `useEffect` with empty dependency and returned cleanup function, which is what you said didn't work for you. Does the `events` value change over the life of the component?

Comment: no, the events value - events I am subscribed to, does not change during the life of the component. 
I somehow do not understand why it is not working when I refresh the page. Or what should be done in order to work it also on page reload. When I get to the same page through for example navigation bar, it works as expected. On the first load it works as expected. But not on page reload, when I hit F5

Comment: Are you sure the `events` value doesn't change during the life of the component? You mention "The first attempt removes eventlisteners and adds eventlisteners again each time a new event is passed". Where do new events come from, the `config` object? Or is `config.events` a static array of events to subscribe to? From what I can tell, `events` is closed over in callback scope so I don't see why the cleanup function wouldn't have `events`? What state is being updated? There's none in your example code snippets? Are you sure this code is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

as i can see there is a problem of calling the create listeners
you created the function inside the useEffect but not calling it ,
try to create it outside and call it on the useEffect like you did with removeListeners

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("onMounte with useEffect");
    const createListeners = () => {
      console.log("createListeners called"); // this will not work ...
    };
    return () => {
        console.log("unmount") // will be called when the component going to be unmounted
    };
  }, []);
```